# rust poem-openapi: endpoints in multiple files

Tags: rest, rust, openapi, rust-poem

I'm trying to build a rest api with multiple endpoints. Some of the endpoints can be related to each other more that others, and thus I would like to implement them in multiple files. I have kind of fallen in love with poem for it's simplicity, but I'm willing to give up on that if someone can show a framework that solves my problem in a simpler way (and performance in not a priority for this application).

My hope is that I can implement the methods in the `Endpoint` struct in multiple. In the attempts I have made, I either get an error `conflicting implementations of trait` or `cannot find attribute`. See the implementation for `some_endpoints.rs` for more details on the error. This is a minimal example that can produce the errors I see:

```rust
// main.rs
use poem::{listener::TcpListener, Route};
use poem_openapi::{OpenApi, OpenApiService};

pub struct Endpoints;
#[OpenApi]
impl Endpoints {}

mod some_endpoints;
mod more_endpoints;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let api = OpenApiService::new(Endpoints, "My app", "1.0");

    let docs = api.swagger_ui();
    let app = Route::new()
        .nest("/api", api)
        .nest("/", docs);
    poem::Server::new(TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:3000"))
        .run(app)
        .await
}
```

```rust
// some_endpoints.rs
use super::Endpoints;
use poem_openapi::OpenApi;
use poem_openapi::payload::PlainText;


// If `#[OpenApi]` here, I get the following errors:
//   error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `OpenApi` for type `Endpoints`
//   conflicting implementation for `Endpoints`
#[OpenApi]
impl Endpoints {
    /// Some dummy endpoints
    ///
    // If `#[OpenApi]` is commented out above, I get the following errors:
    //   error: cannot find attribute `oai` in this scope
    #[oai(path = "/dummy", method = "get")]
    async fn dummy(&self) -> PlainText<&'static str> {
        PlainText("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

```rust
// more_endpoints.rs
// This is basically a copy of `some_endpoints.rs`, and can be left out of 
// this example if `Endpoint` can be first defined in `main.rs`.
```

```ini
# Cargo.toml
# ...
[dependencies]
poem = "1.3.55"
poem-openapi = { version = "2.0.26", features = ["swagger-ui"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer - hiding in plain sight in the documentation.

[This example](https://github.com/poem-web/poem/blob/master/examples/openapi/combined-apis/src/main.rs) shows how to combine multiple structs.

In the original problem I posted, it looks like:

```rust
// main.rs
use poem::{listener::TcpListener, Route};
use poem_openapi::OpenApiService;

mod more_endpoints;
mod some_endpoints;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let all_endpoints = (some_endpoints::Endpoints, more_endpoints::Endpoints);
    let api = OpenApiService::new(all_endpoints, "My app", "1.0");

    let docs = api.swagger_ui();
    let app = Route::new().nest("/api", api).nest("/", docs);
    poem::Server::new(TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:3000"))
        .run(app)
        .await
}
```

```rust
// some_endpoints.rs
use poem_openapi::OpenApi;
use poem_openapi::payload::PlainText;

pub struct Endpoints;

#[OpenApi]
impl Endpoints {
    /// Some dummy endpoints
    ///
    #[oai(path = "/dummy", method = "get")]
    async fn dummy(&self) -> PlainText<&'static str> {
        PlainText("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```